# 'POST' or 'PUT' or 'DELETE' is not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Here the class `WriteByAdminOnlyPermission` is not working perfectly. This `if request.method == 'GET':` working but remaining condition is not working. My target is, only the admin can change information and the other people just can see. How can I do it? And where I did do wrong? please give me a relevant solution

***Note:*** I used here custom User

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, error_messages={"unique":"The email must be unique!"})
    REQUIRES_FIELDS = ["email"]
    objects = CustomeUserManager()
```

***views.py:***

```
class WriteByAdminOnlyPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user

        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True

        if request.method in['POST' or 'PUT' or 'DELETE'] and user.is_superuser:
            return True
        return False

class ScenarioViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes=[WriteByAdminOnlyPermission]
    serializer_class = ScenarioSerializer
    queryset = Scenario.objects.all()
```

***models.py:***

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True, blank=False)
    film_id = models.OneToOneField(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ScenarioFilmID", null=True)
```

***serializer.py:***

```
class ScenarioSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = "__all__"
```

**urls.py:**

```
router.register(r"scenario", views.ScenarioViewSet , basename="scenario")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using `or` operator in list, it can be simplified as `['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']`so:

```py
if request.method in ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'] and user.is_superuser:
```

### Edit

Try to use the `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` class directly to allow unauthenticated users to perform `GET` requests and authenticated users to perform `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` requests so:

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, BasePermission

class WriteByAdminOnlyPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user

        if request.method in ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'] and user.is_superuser:
            return True        
        return IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly().has_permission(request, view)

class ScenarioViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [WriteByAdminOnlyPermission]
    serializer_class = ScenarioSerializer
    queryset = Scenario.objects.all()
```

As defined by you in the below comment as removing [`DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_authentication_classes) worked for you.

Comment: oh I did mistake during the writing but it still not working,,,

Comment: Not it has shown:"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Comment: @Mossaddak It seems that the user is not authenticated.

Comment: yes,,but I already logged into Django admin dashboard

Comment: I solved It bro,, thnk you....I actually usde JWT..I removed DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES,,then it started to work